# How change image in pictureBox when stay on tabpage whitout switch on tabpages

Tags: c#, picturebox

in this code when I stay on tabpage image not changed in pictureBox but when switch tabpage image show in pictureBox I need when stay on tabpage that have picturBox, image change.

```
    private void picLastCap3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
```

{

```
picture.Image = picLastCap3.Image;
picture.Update();
tabControl2.TabPages[1].Refresh();
tabControl2.TabPages[1].Update();
```

}

Comment: on what event you want to change image, from your code seems like you want to change image of picture when piclLastCap3 's image changes, am i right?

Comment: yes when change image on picLastcap3 this image load and show on pictureBox in tabpage[1] when we stay on tabpage[1].

Comment: so why don't you set image of picture when u are setting image of picLastcap3 at the same time

Comment: and make sure your paint event is working check it by adding breakpoint inside paint event that it fires everytime when the image changes or not.

Comment: if not working generate event again

Comment: becuse setting image for picplate3 do in function and time very important after setting image in function set to picturebox out of function but I do your guide tnx alot.